Spring Integration Restore ReactorContext into Imperative Processing
With our complex IntegrationFlow that switches between Reactive and Imperative processing, we are seeing a behavior where the ObservationContext (traceId) is changed right after WebFlux.outboundGateway call.
We followed the documentation and are able to see the reactorContext available via IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.REACTOR_CONTEXT message header, however unable to restore this to ThreadLocal for Imperative processing.
what to be done at the below sample for restoring the ObservationContext from Reactor to Imperative.
IntegrationFlow.from(someChannel())
   .handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway(m -> url, webClient)
                  .httpMethod(POST)
                  .expectedResponseType(String.class),
           ec -> ec.customizeMonoReply((message, mono) -> mono.contextCapture()))
   // what should be done to restore same reactorContext to imperative
   .log(DEBUG, m -> "Imperative Processing starts, as well traceId is changed here :(")
   .......
   .get();


Do you use Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation() ? Might be great if you can share a simple project where we can reproduce. Thanks

yes, we use Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation() and we don't miss traceId anywhere. Only problem is traceId getting changed right after the WebFlux call.  Sure, let me try a sample project to replicate. However, as mentioned in the documentation is something to be done to restore samecontext for imperative processing or Spring Integration framework is already taking care of it? Thx

Did you try with that mono.contextWrite(StaticMessageHeaderAccessor.getReactorContext(message)) instead?

Might be the fact that your WebFlux.outboundGateway() is not a part of an observation, therefore there is nothing to contextCapture(). According to the docs that IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.REACTOR_CONTEXT  is written only from the WebFluxInboundEndpoint. So, not clear from your question how you got there.

Please try this https://github.com/syedyusufh/simple-handle-reactive.git

Thanks. Looking into that. Somehow it turned out that I have such a project locally. Perhaps we have met before :smile:.

Yes. used the same had shared earlier. Btw, please pull again as I have included customWebClientLogger to confirm the existence of ObservationContext in reactive process

Apparently this use-case is not covered.
The reply from WebClient is handled on a different thread. And, as a fact, of direct execution, the rest of your flow. We can see that in logs of your application:
2024-06-21T13:14:12.835-04:00  INFO 22896 --- [   scheduling-1] [6675b4e4be3310898a8c92da890368d1-0d73b0e98d89cc04] c.i.sample.config.TracingConfig          : Request Headers: [Content-Type:"application/json", traceparent:"00-6675b4e4be3310898a8c92da890368d1-0d73b0e98d89cc04-00"]
2024-06-21T13:14:13.522-04:00  INFO 22896 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] [6675b4e4be3310898a8c92da890368d1-0d73b0e98d89cc04] c.i.sample.config.TracingConfig          : Response Headers: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*", Alt-Svc:"h3=":443"; ma=2592000", Content-Type:"application/json", Date:"Fri, 21 Jun 2024 17:14:13 GMT", Server:"Caddy", Vary:"Accept-Encoding", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked"]
2024-06-21T13:14:13.544-04:00  INFO 22896 --- [oundedElastic-1] [6675b4e535753091d2d42ee9db350fa5-5e379125e41a00e1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : WebClient Response (with diferent traceId) in Imperative: {

It is done from here in AbstractMessageProducingHandler:
return reactiveReply.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).toFuture();

I'm not sure why we do thread switching here, but we are loosing that context somehow.
I found a workaround for you:
            .handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway(ECHO_GET, webClient)
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(new ExecutorSubscribableChannel())
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, m -> "WebClient Response (with diferent traceId) in Imperative: " + m.getPayload())

That .channel(new ExecutorSubscribableChannel()) is not involved in the observation handling, so the next log() operator is able to restore context from the traceparent message header.
I'd appreciate if you raise a GH issue for the context switching problem when we handle reactive reply.

Thanks a lot, will use the workaround in the actual application. GH raised - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9259
